# What armour do you enchant with aqua infinity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What pieces of armor are you able to put the Aqua Infinity Enchantment on?

Answer (score 4):

Aqua Affinity is a helmet enchantment, which allows you to mine at full speed underwater.

Answer (score -3):

well if you are talking about aqua affinity then the guy above already answered. however if you are talking about the old enchantment aqua -infinity- then it allows you to have infinite breath underwater.

i know its 3 years late but i wanted to help with that.

Comment: I do not believe that an enchantment called "aqua infinity" ever existed. Could you provide a source for that? Also I don't believe this is worth deleting because it is still a somewhat-decent answer.

Comment: I dont have solid proof but i will soon. However i can say, why do people ask whether you can have aqua affinity and respiration at the same time? It makes no sense unless aqua -infinity- existed.

Comment: I am looking in the game files for the minecraft ps3 edition to find it. I will have to somehow find an older version of minecraft though.